# How to set a cusctom multi-marker on maps API v3 codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with custom marker in `codeigniter`.

```
var locations = 

        [
                <?php if(isset($kop)) : ?>
                <?php foreach($kop->result() as $item) : ?>

                <?php
                    switch ($item->kop_jop) {
                        case '1':
                            $image = "http://localhost/kop/assets/icon/hospital.png";
                            break;

                        case '2':
                            $image = "http://localhost/kop/assets/icon/beach.png";
                            break;
                    }
                ?>              
                ['<div class="media"><div class="media-left"><a href="#"><img style="width:125px; height:90px;" class="media-object" src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/images/<?= $item->kop_gambar;?>" alt="..."></a></div><div class="media-body"><h4 class="media-heading"><?= $item->kop_nama ;?><br><p style="font-size:12px;color: #767676;"><div class="addr"><?= $item->kop_alamat;?></div><div id="maker"><?= $image;?></div><div id="lat"><?= $item->kop_latitude;?></div><div id="lng"><?= $item->kop_longitude;?></div></p></h4><?= substr($item->kop_deskripsi, 0, 80);?><br><div id="more_detail"><h5><a href="javascript:click_route()">Rute</a> | <a target="_blank" href="<?= base_url()."detail_kop/" . $item->id_kop; ?>">Detail</a></h5></div></div></div>',<?php echo $item->kop_latitude;?>, <?php echo $item->kop_longitude;?>, <?= echo $image;?>],

                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>     
        ];
SET VIEW

var marker, i;

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map,
                    icon: location[i][3],
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                });

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                  infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
              })(marker, i));
            }
```

Comment: http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/multiplemarkers user this code i think its helpfull for you

Comment: url you gave could not be opened

Comment: [Click here](http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/multiplemarkers)

Comment: Can you please give a little more information? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: I have KOP table with the following data:
id_kop, kop_name, kop_address, kop_latitude, kop_longitude, kop_jop

in kop_jop have enum data type that contains the data 1 and 2

I want to display a marker of outcome data at a variable location, where if the value at $ item-> kop_jop = 1 marker displayed http: //localhost/kop/assets/icon/hospital.png whereas if the value at $ item-> kop_jop = 2, the marker is displayed http: //localhost/kop/assets/icon/beach.png

Comment: @Aslam, can't open here

Comment: http://tips4php.net/2010/10/use-php-mysql-and-google-map-api-v3-for-displaying-data-on-map/

Comment: @Aslam, thank you for giving me an answer, but the problem I faced not only displays many features many marker marker if I have succeeded, I want to ask is showing 2 different types of marker is not like you gave it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a condition on the loop when you're adding Markers

**Note - this is just a pseudocode**

```
...
if (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    var image = "[default]";
    if (array[i].kop_jop == 1){
        image = "http://localhost/kop/assets/icon/hospital.png";
    } else {
        image = "http: //localhost/kop/assets/icon/beach.png";
    }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: array[i].lat, lng: array[i].lng},
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
}
...
```

More information about setting Markers can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)